# Slick.js set classes for all slides before and after the centered one

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slick.js, classname

I'm using slick.js carousel, I need to set different styles to the all the slides that comes before and all the slides that comes after the centered one.

So I used these css style rules:

```
.slick-slide{background-color:lime;}
.slick-center{background-color:blue;}
.slick-center ~ .slick-slide{background-color:red;}
```

I have two issues:

1. The .slick-center class, with 5 elements sliding for example, at the end of the slide's animation is not applied to the centered slide: https://codepen.io/jean-chiementin/pen/NWYXZmB
2. By using '.slick-center ~ .slick-slide' at the end of the slide's animation before the slide return to the start position all slides becomes red:https://codepen.io/jean-chiementin/pen/RwMQbWv

So how can I set specific classes for before,center,after slides using jquery or javascript?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about a css solution but you could use the slider change event to work out which side the current (centre) and from there find the sides on either side

```js
$('.your-element').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  console.log(nextSlide);
});
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I can't figure out how can I add a class to currentSlide, i tried $(currentSlide).addClass('my_current'); but is not working. 'your-element' must be the container of the slider?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it works but the class is added after the animation slide, if I use beforeChange event it add the class on the slide that was the current before the animation slide:

```
$('.cont').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){

    $(".slick-slide").each(function(){
      var mio_attr = $(this).attr('data-slick-index');
      if(mio_attr == currentSlide){
        $(this).addClass('my_current');
      }
      else{$(this).removeClass('my_current');}
    });
  

});
```

[here](https://codepen.io/jean-chiementin/pen/wvmywMv) the pencode example

Answer (score 0):

If you use the swiper solution: https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api

it will give you what I believe you want, it supports:

next slide class:
https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-slideNextClass

next previous slide class
https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-slidePrevClass

and current slide class
https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-slideActiveClass

its generally more customisable and there isn't much difference between how it works and the version your using, only it has more features you can plug into

https://codepen.io/ptahume/pen/eYMVLPJ

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  const swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    autoplay: false,
    rewind:true,
    spaceBetween: 5,
    centeredSlides: true,
    slidePrevClass : "my-prev-slide-class",
   slideActiveClass: "my-current-slide-class",
    slideNextClass: "my-next-slide-class",

    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
      clickable: true
    },
    navigation: {
      nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
      prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body{background-color:#444;}
.mySwiper{padding-top:0px;width:20%;margin-left:40%;min-height:100px;background-color:lightgray;}
article{width:100px;min-height:100px;margin:0 10px;text-align:center;}
p{text-align:center;}
.slick-list{overflow:visible!important;}/**/
.mySwiper {
  overflow:visible!important;;
}
.my-prev-slide-class{background-color:lime!important;}
.my-next-slide-class{background-color:blue!important;}
.my-current-slide-class{border-bottom:5px solid orange;}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="swiper mySwiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <article id="" class="et_pb_post">
        <p>1 bau</p>
      </article>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <article id="" class="et_pb_post">
        <p>2 ciccio</p>
      </article>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <article id="" class="et_pb_post">
        <p>3</p>
      </article>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <article id="" class="et_pb_post">
        <p>4</p>
      </article>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <article id="" class="et_pb_post">
        <p>5</p>
      </article>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
  </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps